# Bypassing a proxy

Tags: proxy, bypass

When connected to the school Wifi, the only way to actually be able to use the internet I need to have the school proxy set up, which obviously filters content.

Is there any way I can bypass this proxy?

Comment: Bear in mind school filtering systems can be quite sophisticated and can still log activity and produce screenshots, so maybe if you want to check your facebook, I suggest doing it on your phone or waiting until you get home ;) Also depends on the SysAdmin's view of proxy useage.

Comment: The Firewall may be setup to only allow connections coming from the proxy server, which would make bypassing it difficult.

Comment: Buy an iPhone, browse the internet that way for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried services like [Hide My Ass!](http://www.hidemyass.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a quick search on google for Proxy avoidance or Free Proxy server.

As long as your school websense doesn't block Proxy avoidance search.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which website do you want to use, if you need to access some websites which are not accessible, you can trick it by using different services, see:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-get-into-blocked-websites-in-school-with-freeproxy/
http://www.tothepc.com/archives/10-ways-to-access-blocked-gmail-at-office-school-work/
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080513054132AAmNdxg

If you are using Linux, you could use corkscrew or connect-proxy (SSH through http proxy).

Comment: This is just a bunch of links.  Doesn't really offer any guidence.  It certainly does not explain HOW to bypass the proxy.

Comment: links which are providing solutions, so I don't have to copy and paste the instructions. I was reading them by my-self, if you don't have problem with proxy, don't read the answers.